# How to keep QComboBox from expanding last chosen item with qdarkstyle theme

Tags: python, qcombobox, qtstylesheets, pyside2

I have a Pyside2 application that is using the [qdarkstyle theme](https://github.com/ColinDuquesnoy/QDarkStyleSheet). I am trying to use a QComboBox widget, but the selected item gets blown up to a huge size that makes the widget unusable.

Relevant UI setup code I used to add the combo box (generated by pyuic5) with a MainWindow creation to provide a reproducible example:

*Note: To run this code you will need the qdarkstyle theme as well as PySide2, which can be installed with:* `pip install qdarkstyle`

```py
from PySide2 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
import qdarkstyle
import sys

class Ui_Dialog(object):
    def setupUi(self, Dialog):
        Dialog.setObjectName("Dialog")
        Dialog.resize(875, 527)
        self.comboBox = QtWidgets.QComboBox(Dialog)
        self.comboBox.setObjectName("comboBox")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.retranslateUi(Dialog)
        self.comboBox.setCurrentIndex(4)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Dialog)

    def retranslateUi(self, Dialog):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Dialog.setWindowTitle(_translate("Dialog", "Dialog"))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(0, _translate("Dialog", "1 day"))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(1, _translate("Dialog", "1 week"))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(2, _translate("Dialog", "3 months"))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(3, _translate("Dialog", "6 months"))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(4, _translate("Dialog", "1 year"))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(5, _translate("Dialog", "3 years"))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(6, _translate("Dialog", "5 years"))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(7, _translate("Dialog", "max"))

class Dialog(QtWidgets.QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Dialog, self).__init__()
        self.ui = Ui_Dialog()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Dialog()
    window.show()
    app.setStyleSheet(qdarkstyle.load_stylesheet_pyside2())
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

When I open up the combobox, the item that was last chosen will increase in size as shown in the image below:
[image: blown up item in combobox]

I tried to revert back to the default qt theme, and everything worked fine, so I suspect that this has something to do with the qdarkstyle theme that I am using. Any help or tips are greatly appreciated!

Comment: Ok, I added the code that I used to generate the UI with the combobox

Comment: I do not have that problem in Arch Linux with PySide2 5.13.0 and qdarkstyle 2.7: https://i.imgur.com/RjJwDyR.png , I think that you have a bug so it is recommended that you report it to qdarkstyle.

Comment: Ok, thank you for trying it out for me. I'm running Mint so that may be the issue.
Extra Edit: I just checked and I also have PySide2 5.13.0 and qdarkstyle 2.7

Answer (score 1):

This issue is probably due to my OS or some other system settings, since this does not seem like a common bug.

After @eyllanesc tried to reproduce my code and everything worked fine for them, I [submitted an issue](https://github.com/ColinDuquesnoy/QDarkStyleSheet/issues/200) on the qdarkstyle repo. One of the devs ([@goanpeca](https://github.com/goanpeca)) suggested to add the following code to fix the problem:

```py
from PySide2 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
...
    delegate = QtWidgets.QStyledItemDelegate()
    self.comboBox = QtWidgets.QComboBox(Dialog)
    self.comboBox.setItemDelegate(delegate)
```

This helped to remove the expansion of the last chosen item, but now the combobox opens higher than expected, instead of dropping down from the chooser.

**Unopened:**

[image: Unopened Combobox]

**Opened:**

[image: Opened Combobox]

According to the developer, this issue will be looked into, but the fix that he provided is a great improvement. Hopefully this helps anyone who may run into a similar problem! (someone with Manjaro as their OS also stumbled upon this bug as detailed in [this issue](https://github.com/borgbase/vorta/issues/326) for another qdarkstyle application)

Comment: This fixed the issue for my program on Mac OS. It does not occur in Windows.